# Can TeamSQL do a dump to file

Tags: teamsql

I have just started using TeamSQL (an hour ago).  Does it have the ability to dump complete databases or tables with structure, data, or both?

I am used to using phpMyAdmin but working with PostgreSQL now and unimpressed with phpPgAdmin.

I am unfortunately on Windows if that makes a difference.

Comment: i'll take that as a no

Answer (score 2):

TeamSQL doesn't have that feature, but you can export your result sets using export options (as CSV, JSON, etc.. )

Right click on the gridview and you'll see "Export Table" option;

[image]

Comment: yes, those options are obvious, but JSON, CSV are not useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

I have learned how to use command line pg_dump.exe to get my SQL files.

eg.
`pg_dump -U postgres -d mydatabase --inserts -O > postgres.sql`

use `pg_dump -?` and Google for details.

Comment: the sad part is that I use 3 different programs now to accomplish what phpMySql did all on its own.